# Advise on how to handle a mistake when reviewing

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Just after a bit of advise as I am not sure what I should do under the circumstances.
I approved [the suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28330945) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212029/im-attempting-to-retrieve-the-dimensions-of-in-memory-video-buffer-objects-in-n) then realised I should not have approved it as it actually changes the code. I flagged it and commented in the flag that it was approved in error but it was declined as "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".  So what is the correct process to take if you make an error?

Comment: You have editing privileges so you can roll back to the first revision ([look in the history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66212029/revisions)) if you feel it would be undone.